# Magento 2 frontend Router list

Tags: magento2, routes

I want to get all list of  the front routers in Magento2 I have checked with default Magento2 vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config.php's _getRoutes that return all the front routes

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in the controller class to get the controller, module, action and route name:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $moduleName = $this->request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $this->request->getControllerName();
        $action     = $this->request->getActionName();
        $route      = $this->request->getRouteName();
        echo $moduleName."<br/>";
        echo $controller."<br/>";
        echo $action."<br/>";
        echo $route."<br/>";
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```